# Bad envelope tag: SOAP service

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

When I try to test a SOAP request, I get the following error in the console

> Bad envelope tag:  EbMtvnSvcReq

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Bad envelope tag:  EbMtvnSvcReq</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">d05jbapp12</ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am testing this SOAP request in Postman tool.

Here is my request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/request" xmlns:com="http://metavante.com/types/common" xmlns:req1="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/consumer/request" xmlns:com1="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/common" xmlns:req2="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/event/request" xmlns:req3="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/statistics/request" xmlns:req4="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/notification/request" xmlns:req5="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/security/request" xmlns:req6="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/paymentRule/request" xmlns:req7="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/fi/request" xmlns:req8="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/fundingProfile/request" xmlns:req9="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/transferAccount/request" xmlns:req10="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/merchant/request" xmlns:req11="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/consumerPayee/request" xmlns:req12="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/payment/request" xmlns:req13="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/user/request" xmlns:req14="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/bill/request" xmlns:req15="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/category/request" xmlns:req16="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/report/request" xmlns:req17="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/alert/request" xmlns:req18="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/banking/request" xmlns:req19="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/messaging/request" xmlns:req20="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/recipient/request" xmlns:req21="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/transfer/request" xmlns:req22="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/transferRule/request" xmlns:req23="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/giftcard/request"> 
     <soapenv:Header>
    <ActivityId xmlns="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/request" CorrelationId="10018d27-2573-4d6b-8bcb-b49f6c686f1a">5d827c1d-bd7b-437f-904f-5f82c9844022</ActivityId>
    </soapenv:Header>  

    <soapenv:Body>  
       <req:EbMtvnSvcReq> 
          <req:MtvnSvcVer>v1.1.0</req:MtvnSvcVer>  
          <req:MsgUUID>eE64A6fA-c7Dc-1e3f-D95E-94092c95B5A7</req:MsgUUID> 
          <req:PrcsParms> 
             <req:SrcID>MVEPAY</req:SrcID> 
          </req:PrcsParms> 
          <req:Svc> 
             <req:SvcParms> 
                <req:ApplID>ZELLE_UAT</req:ApplID>  
                <req:SvcID>GetConsumerDetails</req:SvcID> 
                <req:SvcVer>v1.6.0</req:SvcVer> 
                 <req:RqstUUID>892e6e60-294d-451a-9c65-5f09c8f0e999</req:RqstUUID>
                <req:RoutingID>sandbox</req:RoutingID> 
             </req:SvcParms> 
             <req:MsgData> 
                <req:GetConsumerDetails> 
                   <com:channelName>WEB</com:channelName>
                   <com:locale>en-US</com:locale> 
                   <com:userId>JimZelle1</com:userId>  
                </req:GetConsumerDetails> 
             </req:MsgData> 
          </req:Svc> 
       </req:EbMtvnSvcReq>  
    </soapenv:Body> 
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Your example isn't a valid XML document, you don't have a closing element for the Header or Envelope elements. I doubt that this is really the problem so please check your inputs and make sure you are reproducing **exactly** the input you are using

Comment: My actual xml request has  Header and Enevlope , here also i added same but it's not taking, if you want, just edit and see. Please provide your inputs thank you .

Comment: If you have html/xml tags here that are not code (aka. indented with 4 spaces), it will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You SOAPMessage i.e. SOAPEnvelope is in correct, your missing,
`</soap:Header>` and `</soap:Envelope>` enclosing Tags.

Correct XML should be something like below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:req="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/request" xmlns:com="http://metavante.com/types/common" xmlns:req1="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/consumer/request" xmlns:com1="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/common" xmlns:req2="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/event/request" xmlns:req3="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/statistics/request" xmlns:req4="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/notification/request" xmlns:req5="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/security/request" xmlns:req6="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/paymentRule/request" xmlns:req7="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/fi/request" xmlns:req8="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/fundingProfile/request" xmlns:req9="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/transferAccount/request" xmlns:req10="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/merchant/request" xmlns:req11="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/consumerPayee/request" xmlns:req12="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/payment/request" xmlns:req13="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/user/request" xmlns:req14="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/bill/request" xmlns:req15="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/category/request" xmlns:req16="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/report/request" xmlns:req17="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/alert/request" xmlns:req18="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/banking/request" xmlns:req19="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/messaging/request" xmlns:req20="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/recipient/request" xmlns:req21="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/transfer/request" xmlns:req22="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/transferRule/request" xmlns:req23="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/giftcard/request"> 
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ActivityId xmlns="http://epayments.metavante.com/types/request" CorrelationId="10018d27-2573-4d6b-8bcb-b49f6c686f1a">5d827c1d-bd7b-437f-904f-5f82c9844022</ActivityId>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>  
        <req:EbMtvnSvcReq> 
            <req:MtvnSvcVer>v1.1.0</req:MtvnSvcVer>  
            <req:MsgUUID>eE64A6fA-c7Dc-1e3f-D95E-94092c95B5A7</req:MsgUUID> 
            <req:PrcsParms> 
                <req:SrcID>MVEPAY</req:SrcID> 
            </req:PrcsParms> 
            <req:Svc> 
                <req:SvcParms> 
                    <req:ApplID>ZELLE_UAT</req:ApplID>  
                    <req:SvcID>GetConsumerDetails</req:SvcID> 
                    <req:SvcVer>v1.6.0</req:SvcVer> 
                    <req:RqstUUID>892e6e60-294d-451a-9c65-5f09c8f0e999</req:RqstUUID>
                    <req:RoutingID>sandbox</req:RoutingID> 
                </req:SvcParms> 
                <req:MsgData> 
                    <req:GetConsumerDetails> 
                        <com:channelName>WEB</com:channelName>
                        <com:locale>en-US</com:locale> 
                        <com:userId>JimZelle1</com:userId>  
                    </req:GetConsumerDetails> 
                </req:MsgData> 
            </req:Svc> 
        </req:EbMtvnSvcReq>  
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: As OP mentions in the comments, the StackOverflow user interface is mangling the content - if you look at the posted content in the post edit history, the document is well-formed.

Comment: My actual xml request has Header and Enevlope , here also i added same but it's not taking, if you want, just edit and see. Please provide your inputs thank you

Comment: I see, it's better you add your wsdl. Seems your server not understanding  req:EbMtvnSvcReq  req namespace or  EbMtvnSvcReq tag.